# Translating set-theoretic concepts to polymorphic type theory or beyond

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, type-theory

I've been trying to read Coquand's "An Analysis of Girard's Paradox" lately. I've noticed that he gets a type-theoretic variant of Burali-Forti's paradox once he extends Church's system with polymorphic types. But I'm having difficulty following the translation of set-theoretic notions into type theory the way he does it; it seems to be part of a more general scheme, which he doesn't get into in much detail.

I'm wondering if there are any references elaborating on the kind of translations of set-theoretic/order-theoretic concepts into polymorphic type theory for someone who isn't far too advanced in the field (and just in case, for those who are).

As a relevant side question: can we translate set theory in its utmost generality into any kind of dependant type theory, in the kind of way that Coquand translates certain set-theoretic concepts into polymorphic type thoery? (Name relevant references please.)

Comment: I think this could answer your last question: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0014566

Comment: I like the phrase "someone who isn't far too advanced in the field".  It's probably a typo for "someone who isn't too far advanced in the field", but I recommend *not* changing it.

Comment: @Matteo thanks. @AndreasBlass indeed I had `too far advanced' in mind, but I'll keep that for you as is.